# How is the holy grail war from Fate/ Stay night kept a secret?

Tags: fate-stay-night, fate-series

I might have missed the explanation while reading the visual novel but if the magic and all that kinda stuff are kept a secret from the public, then how exactly do you explain the huge glaring flashes of light and the huge amount of noise that comes from the fight between the servants? Is it something to do with the Magic Association/ The Church? I don't actually remember any instances in the the visual novel other than the start of the series with Shirou getting stabbed by Lancer where any witnesses were killed. Not to mention the other shenanigans like Rider summoning his chariot.

Comment: I expect it's something like the "closed space" from *Haruhi Suzumiya* - some kind of pocket dimension where the battles can take place without anyone seeing them - but I'm really not familiar with the Fateverse lore, so that's honestly just a guess and not worth posting as an answer.

Comment: @F1Krazy The Fate concept would be that of bounded fields, but they are rarely invoked in FSN and usually cover very limited areas.  Even servants can't really create a bounded field larger than a high school, and modern mages are basically limited to a workshop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the author Kinoko Nasu himself:

> The Holy Grail War is unknown to the general population, but to what extent is it hidden from normal people? Are the Church people (supervisors) manipulating the media and police (or even the governmental level) to cover it up?
> A: The Church manipulates information, while the Magic Association handles the media. Also, the Association has the Einzbern cover the cost of any collateral damage.

[Fate/complete material III: World material - FAQ with Nasu: Holy Grail War, p.131](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/Fuyuki_Holy_Grail_War#cite_note-4)

Eyewitnesses can be dealt with by manipulating their memories.

Comment: *"Eyewitnesses can be dealt with by manipulating their memories."* or strait up killed, lets not forget that we see in *Fate/Zero* the Magic Association sent a team out to the island Kiritsugu and his father live on and killed everyone when trying to cover up Kiritsugu's father's experiments (and not just the Dead Apostles that were created)